# Database Architecture for logging

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-diagram

This is something that has bothered me for a long time and i still have been unable to find an answer.

I have a huge system with alot of different features. What is common for this system is of course that my `users` can

> create, update, read & delete

different parts of my system.

For simple reasons lets say i have an application that has the following features:

- Document administration
- Video administration
- User administration
- Salery administration

(Please do note i took these at random just to prove a point that all of these would have their own separate tables and does not necessarily be connected).

Now i wish to create some sort of logging system. So that when ever someone either create,update or delete an entity it will be recorded.

Now as far as i can see i can do this two ways.

1.

Create a logging table for each of the 4 features that is in my system. However with this method i am required to create a logging table for each new feature i add to the system. i would also have to combine data from X number of tables if i wish to create a log which potentially could be a huge task!

2.

i could create something like the following:

[image]

However once again i would have to add a col for each new feature i will add.

So my question is what is the best way for creating logging database architecture

Or is there an easier way?

Comment: You can just have an `actionTaken` and `dateOfAction` field and insert a specific action everytime a user add, alters or delete anything from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of one target_xx for each feature, you could do it this way:

```
target_id | target_type
1           video
4           document
5           user
2           user
```

or even better. A table with target types and insert only the respective id's on target_type

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you want to capture for each table creation and update date, i would just use the default and the update event from mysql. You can define the fields like this for a table:

```
ALTER TABLE table 
ADD COLUMN CreateDate Datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
ADD COLUMN LastModifiedDate Datetime ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

You can add these 2 fields in all tables. If you want to use one central table for logging (which might be more difficult to manage, because you always need to create joins, maybe also worse performance), then I would work with triggers.